# Is there a way to get all users from a specific company via the GitHub API?

Tags: api, github

I'm trying to return a relatively accurate list of people by company via the GitHub API. I'm not seeing a way to do that in the advanced search UI, and the CLI isn't turning up much either.

[image: GitHub advanced search: user section]

The query: https://github.com/search?q=GitHub+in%3Acompany&type=Users turns up people who have the company listed in their usernames or email addresses.

The query: https://github.com/search?q=repos%3A1+company%3AGitHub&type=Users returns nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That field isn't indexed for searching. Gotta make the recruiters work for their money. ;-)

https://twitter.com/pengwynn/status/656888158018113536

Must be a symptom of the "new GitHub"... https://twitter.com/holman/status/592757813107101697